# Question on calculating throughput

Tags: probability, statistics

`Here is the necessary information:

A file contains:

- A header of size of **h** bits
- Data component of size **d** bits
- There is a probability **b** that a bit will be dropped (ruining the file)

The connection can support a maximum of **c** bits/second

I need to:

- Calculate the probability a file will be ruined. Already did this: **(1-b)^(h+d)**
- Compute the throughput over the link. (**h** remains the same size, so what is the optimal value for **d**?)

I'm having problems coming up with a function to model the number of files being sent through.  If I could do that, I think it would be simple to maximize it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have removed [calculus] and [logic] since they most definitely did not fit the question. I am not even sure about [probability] and [statistics], but I cannot decide in this case. I am also not too sure what tag would fit here instead of these four. I will leave it to more competent folks, then...

Answer (score 1):

Your throughput is about $c (1-b)^{h+d} \dfrac{d}{h+d}$, which you want to maximise by changing $d$.

If you take the derivative with respect to $d$ and set this to 0, I think you may find yourself solving $d^2+hd +h/\log_e(1-b)=0$

Answer (score 0):

Since $d$ is an integer, I don't like taking the derivative with 
respect to $d$ as @Henry has suggested.  So, as an alternative,
taking the throughput to be $c(1-b)^{h+d} \frac{d}{h+d}$, we look 
at what happens if we increase $d$ by $1$.  The throughput is 
now $c(1-b)^{h+d+1} \frac{d+1}{h+d+1}$ and we can examine the ratio
$$
\frac{c(1-b)^{h+d}\frac{d}{h+d}}{c(1-b)^{h+d+1} \frac{d+1}{h+d+1}}
= \frac{d(h+d+1)}{(1-b)(d+1)(h+d)}
$$
to find the smallest value of $d$ for which the ratio has value $1$
or more.  Once again, the answer is the solution to a quadratic equation
(and only slightly different from Henry's result).

The maximum throughput of a different model of the transmission process, 
in which
the transmission errors are detected at the receiving end, a
request for a repeat of the file transmission is sent to the 
transmitter, and file transmissions are repeated until the 
file is successfully received 
(an [ARQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction#Automatic_repeat_request) system),
is discussed 
[here](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece313/fall00/ppt/Lecture17.pdf).